# How to add snapcraft sources in flathub Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)

Tags: snapcraft, flatpak, snap, flatpak-builder

Well I don't know how to do it but I found some interesting guidelines while browsing and using ChatGPT & Google Bard AI.

To add Snapcraft sources to Flathub, follow these steps:

1. **Add Flathub Remote:**

First, make sure you have Flatpak and Flathub set up on your system. If not, install Flatpak and add the Flathub repository as a remote using the following commands:

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

2. **Edit the Flatpak Manifest:**

Now, you'll need to create or edit a Flatpak manifest file (.json or .yaml). This file describes how to build and package your application. In this file, you'll specify the Snapcraft source URL.

3. **Add Snapcraft Source:**

Inside the manifest file, look for the sources section. Add the Snapcraft source URL and other necessary details. Here's a simplified example:

```
json file

{
    "id": "your.application.ID",
    "runtime": "org.gnome.Platform",
    "runtime-version": "40",
    "sdk": "org.gnome.Sdk",
    "command": "your-application-command",
    "modules": [
        {
            "name": "your-application",
            "buildsystem": "simple",
            "sources": [
                {
                    "type": "archive",
                    "url": "https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/snap-name/current/meta/"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

4. **Build and Install:**

Build the Flatpak using the modified manifest:

```
flatpak-builder build-directory your-application.json --force-clean
```

5. **Install the Flatpak:**

Install the built Flatpak:

```
flatpak install build-directory your.application.ID
```

Replace "your.application.ID" and "your-application-command" with appropriate values for your application. Adjust the manifest and Flatpak commands as needed for your specific case.

Remember to replace "https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/snap-name/current/meta/" with the actual Snapcraft source URL you want to use.

Comment: What's your question?